# \Sqrt{x} in terminal png enhanced

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using Gnuplot, and I would to get root square symbol in xlabel of a png file, so I set xlabel like this:
set xlabel '\sqrt{4x}/x'
but in .png file  I did'nt find any conversion of the \sqrt to symbol
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the `latex` terminal ? If not, can't work that way.

Comment: no I'm juste using png terminal

Answer (score 1):

Without using the latex terminal, it appears to be not possible using the bitmap terminals.
The closest you can get is to use the [enhanced text mode](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/enhancedtext.html) and entering a ["square root" character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm).

However, you can not directly enter the Unicode code point, directly or using utf8 encoding.
Instead, check out [that table](http://ayapin-film.sakura.ne.jp/Gnuplot/Docs/ps_guide.pdf), it appears that it can be produced with the octal value 326.

So the demo code will be:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set termoption enhanced
set output "aa.png"
set ylabel "{/Symbol=\326}x/x"
plot sqrt(sin(x))/x
```

Comment: Gnuplot supports utf-8 also in version 4.x

Comment: @Christoph You're right, I just meant that you cannot enter directly the utf8 value with the enhanced text mode. Editing.

Comment: On Windows you can use utf8 only inside of scripts, `wgnuplot` doesn't support that, yet. But that's being worked on, https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/patches/727/

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot supports unicode in modern versions.  If the terminal you are interfacing with it through supports unicode, you can just enter the unicode character directly (different os's will use a different method for doing that).  Provided the font you are using in the png terminal supports the character, it will appear in the final plot.

On windows, this doesn't work because neither the wgnuplot.exe executable or windows command prompt allows unicode.  You can supply it through a script file (provided the file is encoded with utf-8) and run it with the gnuplot.exe executable.

For example, we can create the script<sup>**†**</sup>

```
set term png
set output "squareroot.png"
plot sqrt(x) t "√x"
set output
```

and then run it with `gnuplot scriptfile` to produce

[image: Example with square root]

For another example, let's suppose that we want the title to be a run of smiley faces (unicode character 263A), we can use the following script<sup>**‡**</sup>

```
set term png
set output "squareroot.png"
set title "☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺"
plot sqrt(x) t "√x"
set output
```

which produces

[image]

---

<sup>**†**</sup> I created this script in notepad.exe and made sure that the encoding was set to utf-8.  To type the squareroot symbol, I held the alt key and typed 251, as recommended at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm.  Windows makes it difficult to type the unicode value directly, but it is possible with a registry setting.  The method I used references the active code page.

<sup>**‡**</sup> Without the registry modification, we can't type the smiley face in windows.  However, a very simple line of python 3 code (`open("testsq.txt","wb").write("\u263a".encode("utf-8"))`) dumps the smiley face symbol to a text file, which we can then open (in utf-8 mode) and copy and paste to the script.